# PCA for data compression

Tags: compression, pca

I am in a discussion on whether you can save disk space by doing PCA on your data. Suppose you have a covariance matrix and your data vectors are of length 1000. The compression method to cut space by 50% would be:

- derive a matrix that rotates the covariance matrix into diagonal form such that the eigenvalues are along the diagonal.
- drop the smallest 500 diagonal elements - replace by zero
- rotate the result using the transpose of the original rotation.

Me: This doesnt save any space for the vectors because there will still be nonzero elements in all the 1000 components after rotation. There is no compression. The data are probably simplified but that is a different thing.
Him: just take the first 500 elements in the result - that is your "compression".

I know I am right but plenty of people say in the literature that they are doing compression with PCA - here is an example:

http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/PCAWhitening/

I think that this tutorial is mostly right and is a nice description but the conclusion on compression is wrong. But how could something so obvious be overlooked by people who clearly work with data. Makes me things that I am wrong.

Can anyone help me understand their viewpoint?

Comment: What is the PCA? Is it Principal Components Analysis? **What is the data to compress**? Can you change data after compression-decompression cycle (what is allowed error), or you need exact ([lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression)) method?

Comment: PCA does refer to principal component analysis in this context. Imagine that the data to compress is a photograph, organized as one long vector by concatenation rows of the photograph. Or really any data stored as one long vector. The compression can, of course, be lossy, as one would expect for PCA. Finally, a compression-decompression cycle can have, say, some specified error that will be controlled by the spectral cutoff. Thanks for helping to clarify.

Comment: abby, the "nonzero elements in all the 1000 components after rotation" may have more predictable distribution than before. When values are predictable, they can be stored in less space with some ["entropy encoding" method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_encoding). Also, there are some papers about PCA application to images in the Scholar Search.

Comment: If your matrix is now mostly 0, there exist many [methods to store it efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion:

1- Yes, you can compress data by PCA because the dimension of the vectors (each one) you have to store is less than the original. Of course, you have to store the matrix to decompress the data too, but if your original dataset is enough large, this is insignificant to the data itself.

2- Of course there is a drawback. The compression is not lossless. You lose the original data forever, and your new version after decompression won't be exactly the same as the original. It will be an approximation.

At this point here's my advice:

If you have a lot of data with the same form (vectors of the same dimension...), your interest in this data is qualitative (you don't care the exact number itself, only the approximate number) and some of the data shows collinearity (dependency between vectors), PCA is a way to save storage space.

It is imperative to check if you lose the variance of the original data or not, because this is the signal you are choosing too much compression.

Anyway, the main purpose of PCA is not saving storage space... it is to do heavy operations with the data quicker to obtain a very similar result.

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: I would like to add the important caveat that not only is the compression not lossless, but the loss is *not at random*.  PCA targets specific dimensions to remove, and these dimensions may or may not be useful.  The assumption that the top $n$ basis vectors from a PCA are the only "important" ones in your data may be useful sometimes, but does not hold in general.

Comment: Why can't PCA still compress even if we don't remove the less important components?  E.g. if the original elements are, each, represented in 100 variables, most of which are purely redundant, I'd imagine that PCA can represent them in, say, 60 variables, without even losing any information.   Am I wrong?

Comment: In a simple way, try to think about PCA as a linear regression. You start with a 2d point cloud, and the linear regression allows you to simplify it to a 1d point cloud. If all your points are exactly coincident with the regression line, you won't lose any information. But, witch it is the normal case, some points are near the line, but not over it, you will lose the information of the distances between these points and the fit line after the dimensionality reduction.